# How to fire single await/async based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a NodeJS app and I have two async blocks that I am calling but the condition is that if the first block returns a value, I don't want to fire the second block. This is how my code looks:

```
//BLOCK 1
await canFunction1HandleID(id)
.then( () => {
  const result = await functionOne(id);
    if(!result){
      //throw error
    }

    return result;
})

//BLOCK 2
await canFunction2HandleID(id)
.then( () => {
  const result = await functionTwo(id);
    if(!result){
      //throw error
    }

    return result;
})
```

If the first block returns a value, I just want to return that value and not have the second block execute. But right now both blocks are executed, one after another. Any idea why and how can I achieve that I am trying to do here?

TIA.

Comment: Why are you using `await` and `then` at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Just put the first value into a variable?

```
const result1 = await canFunction1HandleID(id)
    .then(() => {
        const result = await functionOne(id);
        if (!result) {
            //throw error
        }
        return result;
    });

if (!result1) {
    const result2 = await canFunction2HandleID(id)
        .then(() => {
            const result = await functionTwo(id);
            if (!result) {
                //throw error
            }
            return result;
        });
};
```

Comment: But my question is still the same - why do they both get called? Is it because the fact that they both get onto the execution stack and then are called asynchronously?

Comment: Why wouldn't they both get called? Given your original code's logic, the only way the second wouldn't get called would be if the first rejected, which will only occur in the case of `if (!result) { throw`. Maybe did you mean to do `if (result) { throw`? (which would satisfy what you're looking for, but makes for *very* odd looking control flow)

Answer (score 0):

If canFunction1HandleID and canFunction2HandleID are functions that return Promise<bool>, what about the following?

```js
//BLOCK 1
if (await canFunction1HandleID(id)) {
  const result = await functionOne(id);

  if (!result) {
    //throw error
  }

  return result;
}

//BLOCK 2
if (await canFunction2HandleID(id)) {
  const result = await functionTwo(id);

  if (!result) {
    //throw error
  }

  return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If the first block returns a value, I just want to return that value and not have the second block execute.

Suppose what you expect is: if `functionOne` has valid return, use it; otherwise try `functionTwo` and throw error if no valid return neither.

The code to implement the logic can be simply like:

```js
const result = await functionOne(id).catch(()=>{}) || await functionTwo(id).catch(()=>{});
if (!result) {
    // throw error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use .then while using await. Async/await is introduced to avoid .then promise calls. you can try this way.

`const result1 = await canFunction1HandleID();`
`if(result1){`
`return result1;`
`}`
`const result2 = await canFunction2HandleID();`
`return result2;`